# Does Mesosphere Marathon run native Linux applications?

Tags: mesosphere, marathon

Marathon is keen on advertising that Marathon runs Docker, but there is nowhere implicitly defined what exactly Marathon can run. Does Marathon run native Linux applications? Can I run JBoss on Marathon and it will automatically offer HA and optimized resource (Task) allocation?

Answer (score 2):

From the [marathon github page](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon):

> It can launch anything that can be launched in a standard shell

For the second part (i.e. JBoss HA) it depends on your definition of JBoss. Marathon will ensure that are n instances of Jboss are running and if one fails start a new instance.
Does this answer your question?

Comment: I've seen that "It can launch anything that can be launched in a standard shell" but I still think it's a bit vague :) why not just say "any process that can be run as a Linux process". I think that is how Docker explain what can be run in a Docker container. So I'm still not 100% sure about this, can it really execute any Linux process? No limitations?

Comment: Yes, any Linux process. You provide URIs for any binaries/data you want Mesos to ship over, and specify the command to execute once the binaries have been unpacked into the sandbox. Mesos can still isolate your application using cgroups, even without Docker.

Answer (score 0):

You can run basically anything. 
`sleep 60` is one simple example. 
Marathon and mesos will fetch a tar ball from any given uri - http, hdfs, local - and extract the tar. You can run any binary in there - or even outside like the example with `sleep`. 
Docker makes shipping the application much more easy though.

Comment: Thanks! What about supporting services? If I run a Java applicatio, where should java be installed?

Comment: You can use the system java. I'd recommend using docker though. It's designed for exactly this use case: Bundle everything you need to run an app/service into an image. Make it run in the same way on your personal computer as well as in production.